# Finding Column ID in SharePoint List

Tags: column, custom-form

I'm not looking for the GUID of my column - I have that. 
What I'm trying to access is the ff# 
Basically I created a custom Edit.aspx form for my list, and then afterwards I added a new field "Project".
Now I need to add that Field to my Edit.aspx form, and all I need to know is the field ID - but I need it in the ff format. (See screenshot attached).
I have tried adding the full GUID instead of the ffID but it's not working. 
Am I an idiot?
FYI: I can't just create a new "Edit" form and get the ffID from that because I'm getting an error message on this list telling me "Could not save list changes to the server" 
Also I can't use PowerShell for this. 
Help? 
Sylv

[image: SP Designer Code on custom form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ff` number only relates to the form.  It has nothing to do with the field itself.

If you want to add an additional field to your form just give it a distinct id number after the `ff` location.  Just make sure you update it in all three spots (`FormField` `id`, `FormField` `__designer:bind`, and `FieldDescription` `id`).

Comment: That's exactly what I thought and tried doing and it wasn't working! Turns out I am a dummy. It was ONE last place I didn't see that I had to change the field name. Thank you!

Comment: @Sylvie I've done the same thing.  Three places to update the `ff` value and three places to update the `FieldName`.  Glad it is working now!